# Why doesn't Internet Explorer follow an upgrade system like FireFox

Tags: firefox, browser, internet-explorer

Is there a reason why IE does not do in-place upgrades like FireFox? When other browsers update they generally do not break but with IE it seems like every version behaves so differently.

Comment: IE11 does get updated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Since IE is so tightly wired into the rest of Windows, if you change IE, Windows functionality can be altered. Microsoft prefers upgrading using their Windows/Microsoft Updates system, which is Invented Here, as opposed to Not Invented Here (for values of Here = Redmond).